# Чем (или с чего) начинается утро?

Tags: грамотная-речь, глаголы, управление

Как лучше и правильнее выразиться?

1. Утро начиналось **запахом** молока.
2. Утро начиналось **с запаха** молока.

Возможно, оба варианта приемлемы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В толковом словаре:
[**начина́ться**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F), -ается; ***нсв.***
3. **чем, с чего.** Иметь в своём начале (о слове, о произведении, книге и т. п.). *Книга начинается предисловием. Опера начинается с увертюры. Его фамилия начинается на "О".*

*Утро начиналось запахом свежего хлеба, криками склочных соседей и торопливыми разговорами спешащих на работу людей* (Н. Довгопол. В поисках Марии Магдалины). [чем?]

*Утро в Париже начинается со сладостного аромата свежеиспеченного багета, воздушного, как облачко, круассана и запаха сливочного кофе* (О. Хуссейн. Букетик лаванды на удачу). [с чего?]

Думаю, что в Вашем случае глобальной разницы нет — приемлемы оба варианта.

Стоит отметить, что есть памятные (известные) выражения, которые воспринимаются только с вопросом "с чего?" (вариант *начинается чем* практически не используется).
*С чего начинается Родина? С чего начинается театр?*